# How to time Javascript Functions right?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, search

I have a serious problem in my app. I wrote a "facebook like" instant search:

There is a:

```
<input id="theinput" type="text" title="New Search"/>
```

Which appears after i select which category i want to search for, exp: rock, heavy metal, pop, indie... so, depending of which category i click javascript sets it's name to a variable for the search page to know what table to search in (being each table a category). So part of the javascript is:

```
$('#rockselector').click(function(){
        fadethings();
        $("#resultdiv").html('<span style="color: #fff; font: 12px Verdana, serif; position: relative; left: 20px; top: 20px;">Search a Rock Artist</span>');
        whichselector = "rock";
        soletsgo();
    });

    //-----------------------------------------------

    $('#heavymetalselector').click(function(){
        fadethings();
        $("#resultdiv").html('<span style="color: #fff; font: 12px Verdana, serif; position: relative; left: 20px; top: 20px;">Search a Heavy Metal Artist</span>');
        whichselector = "heavymetal";
        soletsgo();
    });
```

The 'fadethings()' function will fadeOut the div where you select which category, and it will fadeIn the div which will show the results of the search and the input: 'theinput', shown above. The function 'soletsgo()' will do the search:

```
        function soletsgo(){

$('#theinput').keyup(function(){

    function searchy(){
    value = escape($('#theinput').val());

    if ( value.length > 0){
    $("#autodatathing").load("../searchmaster.php?word="+value+"&cat="+whichselector+""); }  

    } // End of searchy() function

            setTimeout(searchy,1000);

    }); // End of keyup function

} // End Of Function soletsgo()
```

The problem is that when i type something long like: 'The Jimi Hendrix Experience', it repeats the searches, even when i change category and search another artists it keeps on doing the last search until its kinda reached the result for every 'keyup'. I Know what is happening here, but, don't know what to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are triggering the `setTimeout` every time the keyup event gets triggered.  Which results in an ajax request being made every single keypress.

Try something like this:

```
function soletsgo() {
    var timer, jqXHR, input;

    function searchy() {
        var value = escape(input.val());

        if (value.length > 0) {
            // Abort the last ajax request becuase we don't care anymore
            if (jqXHR) jqXHR.abort();
            jqXHR = $.ajax({
                url: "../searchmaster.php",
                data: {
                    "word": value,
                    "cat": whichselector
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#autodatathing").html(data);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    input = $('#theinput').keyup(function() {
        // Clear the timer because they are typing more
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(searchy, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: @HadriandeOliveira there was a typo for `clearTimeout` try again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't define the `searchy` function inside your callback of the `keyup` event. That's not a place where you should define functions. I would always reset the timeout when the user presses a key in your search field that triggers your search function, so it only searches when the user stopped typing.

```
var searchTimeout = false;

function searchy() {
    var value = escape($('#theinput').val());

    if ( value.length > 0){
        $("#autodatathing").load("../searchmaster.php?word="+value+"&cat="+whichselector+"");    
    }
}

$('#theinput').keyup(function(){
    window.clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
    searchTimeout = setTimeout(searchy, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make two global variables. First - `search_in_progress` and if it's `TRUE` - you don't search. On search finish you set it to `FALSE` to let another search shoot. Second variable - `last_search` that won't let you search for the same thing twice.

Comment: But that would cause a major problem: If I type faster than the request needs to finish, I will "loose" request. So I may type "Foo Fighters" and it won't search as by the time I entered the additional letters, the search_in_progress var was FALSE.

Comment: Not really. At the end of the search you check if your `last_search` equals the current field value. If it's not - you do another search.

Comment: Wasn't obvious from your answer, but yes, in that case you would be right :-)

Comment: no. because that doesn't matter as every letter of difference is a new search.

Comment: Every letter is not a new search. New search is queried when last one finished. Another solution would be to add time delay (say 0.5 seconds) and if after it's expiration the value of input changed - fire the delay again. If it's still the same - fire the search. This is a better solution, but a bit harder to implement.